# Can Master Kanzawa make animals sleep at a distance?

Tags: zoology, alternative-medicine, martial-arts

As [seen here](http://simplecapacity.com/2016/07/japanese-master-demonstrates-power-chi-controlling-animals-see/) and other places, like Stan Lee’s Superhumans, Master Kanzawa claims to be able to put animals to sleep at a distance by exchanging "chi energy".

I am doubful this is true, since Chi energy does not exist according to science and such an effect is extremely easy to reproduce - just put some muscle relaxant in the water, then wait, or maybe he's just very boring? (*ducks*).

I wanted to know if there is positive evidence that Mr. Kanzawa is a fraud, or alternatively that his powers work in a more controlled enviroment.

[image: video]

Comment: For clarification, are you questioning whether Mr. Kanzawa can make animals lie down in environments where most people would say they shouldn't, or are you questioning whether he is doing so via a supernatural force that cannot be explained by science?

Comment: Basically both, I'd like to know whether this is a stage trick, and if not, what's the scientific explanation. I don't think that a "supernatural force that cannot be explained by science" can be shown empirically.

Comment: I gave it my best shot, but the answer got deleted because Skeptics.SE only accepts empirical answers and the best I could do was provide a reasonable mathematical model based on empiricially verified science which suggests that this power is not as unreasonable as it appears at first glance.  If you ask on a different kind of forum, you may be able to get more insightful answers.